# if voltage is too high but current too low, then is it dangerous for humans?

Tags: voltage, current

voltage=1000V,current=1/1000Amps, so power=1watt
now is this the same as 1V with 1Amp which is not dangerous to humans.

Does voltage not have any any effect if the current is too low?

Because voltage is energy consumed /charge , so voltage is dangerous independently or not?
why/why not?

> Or is it current that is dangerous, regardless of voltage?

Comment: If you apply 1000V to a human, there's no way the current will be 1mA.

Comment: no it can be in a circuit, dont you know that. If the power output is low,that can easily happen. its like saying if mass is too high acceleration cant be low. F=ma it can be any real number,both in theory and practice.

Comment: Obvious counterexample: static charge. It's quite easy to charge yourself up to several kilovolts, at which point you feel only a mild discomfort when it discharges. Because it's a very short pulse, and doesn't cross internal organs.

Comment: how could you say its several Kilovolts?

Comment: @pjc50 how do you know the current will be limited to 1mA during a discharge? Read Chupacabras answer.

Comment: @koe Your comment makes no sense. When you apply a voltage to something, you create an electric circuit by definition. There's only one guy who can withstand 1000V and let only 1mA through, and his name is Henry.

Comment: @koe because of the distance the sparks can cross, you can calculate the voltage of static charge. You have 2.5kV/mm and a spark from static discharge can cross several millimeters.

Comment: @koe You may be missing the following: If a power source is able to supply only 1W, even if it has 1000 V open-circuit (without anything attached), the voltage *will* drop when applied to a human (e.g. 500Ω) load. The power supply can not deliver 2 A, but only 1 mA. Thus, the voltage will drop to 0.5 V. This might be why you are confused by the answers given. This is simply Ohm’s Law: U=RI. If the supply cannot deliver the I for the given U and R, the U will drop.

Comment: @Jonas W , but if current is say , 100Amps then when entering inside too will remain the same, hence current is dangerous regardless?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev This paper by OnSemi http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/TND410-D.PDF cites the Human Body Model as 6.7A at 10kV - but only for a few nanoseconds. Hazardous to ICs but not to humans.

Comment: Stun guns/tazers use high voltage with low current, so your answer is right there.

Answer (score 4):

Current limited high voltage is indeed not dangerous. Static electricity is a good example.

According to IEC 62368, up to 2mA DC or 0.7mA peak AC is considered safe regardless of voltage. On the other hand 48VDC is normally considered safe but in hospital environment SELV is max 24V. 48VDC can kill you when you have probes inserted inside your body where the electricity can conduct directly through blood vessels.

With regard to unrestricted current, up to 60VDC or 42.4VAC peak is considered safe.

The key word here is *current limited* i.e. the current of a high voltage source is limited by means such as series resistor or an active current limiting device. For a capacitor charged to a given voltage there are voltage/capacitance charts that define safe charge level. At 2kV safe capacitance is quite small.

And, yes, a big electrolytic charged to 1kV will kill you so better stick to small ceramics.

Comment: Different jurisdictions pick different voltages in the 40 to 60v region for 'safe', so I generally hedge that number when I answer this sort of thing

Comment: @Neil_UK defining specific IEC standard is pretty unambiguous, it's up to the engineer to know if it applies or not. In this case it is a relatively new standard mostly implemented in EU countries. Rest of the world is still mostly using IEC 60950 derived standards that can amend it with national regulations.

Comment: Ah! I'd missed the IEC reference, probably as it was in a different paragraph. It is my bad for not reading, but consider me a canary in the coal mine, and the posibility it's a UX thang.

Comment: Note that the 2 mA figure is for externally applied voltage. Many years ago I read of a case of an externally powered, implanted pacemaker whose power supply was improperly grounded. Patient touched the metal bed frame and was killed by leakage. Current was estimated at 47 uA.

Comment: @Barleyman _"... up to 60VDC or 42.4VAC peak is considered safe ..."_ - Did you mean "60VAC peak", or "42.4VAC RMS" (which are the same for sine wave AC)? If not, could you explain why the limit for AC is lower?

Comment: @marcelm Simply because AC can induce fibrillation which is kind of fatal.. DC causes heart to clench up which it's better able to recover from. 30VAC RMS is considered safe. These figures are "safe for anyone" figures so for an "instructed person" e.g. service technicians the limits are much higher. Never mind electronics engineers who can electrocute themselves to their heart's content (or not as it may be).

Comment: @Barleyman Ah, thanks. I did consider the possibility that AC might be more dangerous, but I found it suspicious that you said 42.2V,because for sine waves, 42.4VAC RMS == 60VAC peak :)

Answer (score 3):

Human body has some resistance. This resistance can be 100kΩ or can be as low as 500Ω if you have wet hands (human body resistance is not a constant, it depends on many factors).

If you apply 1000V voltage source on your skin, the current will be much higher that 1mA! (no matter you have dry or wet hands)
If you apply 1V voltage source on your skin, the current will not be 1A. Even you have wet hands, and your body has 500Ω resistance, the current would be 2mA.

Comment: Chupacabras, if current is high, that is dangerous to the body, regardless? It should be as too much charge goes to the body in too less time?

Comment: irrespective of voltage?

Comment: @koe, do you know what is the relation between voltage, current and resistance?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the details of the damage mechanism.

It's generally accepted that to cause cardiac fibrillation, a current of more than 30mA is needed across the chest, for a certain significant amount of time. In which case, a current **limited** to 1mA would be unlikely to kill a healthy adult that way. Somebody with compromised health, or very young or old, might be more fragile.

Let's say that you were standing on top of a ladder, attaching wires to a battery powered door-bell, or modifying a telephone connection. An unexpected 1kV could concentrate your attention so much on the surprise and discomfort, you could fall off the ladder.

Answer (score 2):

Voltage is just a mean to apply current. Professors used to tell us that we're just a bunch of 1kΩ resistors, but actual resistance depends on conditions like wear, type of skin, humidity etc.

If the voltage is too low then you cannot apply high enough current. So high enough voltage is a condition but not a guarantee. Guarantee is high voltage with provided current. Good example of safe high voltage is static electricity - the overall electric charge is very low, so despite extremely high voltage, the current produced is minuscule and all it does is maybe sting a bit(or destroy electric equipment).

Now if you have high voltage source which can provide high current, then you're getting in trouble. Hight current with enough exposure time is what causes the danger. Here's a chart showing how long you can stay safe with certain current flowing through you, this particular one is for AC in frequency from 15Hz to 100Hz:

http://www.elektro.info.pl/images/photos/24/5072/__b_5cdb7b7a846bba3ad8ace544bb08e3c7.jpg

Keep in mind that this is for AC. For DC current, the thresholds are generally 2-4 times higher.

Anywhere in AC-1 area is completely safe(for people without cardiac problems or pacemaker) and generally barely noticeable.

AC-2 is still safe but not recommended, and generally lets you set yourself free from the source on your own.

Anything above is potentially fatal. Line b marks the end of area where you still have control on your body and can potentially deattach yourself, anything  more means you need help.

AC-3 marks an area where there are very likely pathophysiological symptoms such as muscle contractions, problems with breathing, cardiac disorders etc. Still not fatal but really dangerous and the longer you stay the higher possibility of long term damages.

AC-4 is pretty much guaranteed one or many of the following: respiratory arrest, cardiac arrest, burns, and the higher you get, the higher % probability of Ventricular fibrillation. 1A has a 50% probability of VF. AC-4 pretty much means near-certain death if not helped in an instant.

Aside from the pure reaction of your body, there's also an aspect of surroundings. If you happen to be on a ladder, then even AC-2 can suprise you enough to make you jump back and cause a dangerous fall. AC-3 is very likely to cause muscle contractions so it can literally sweep you off your feet and make you lose your balance, again causing another type of danger.